# Android/java. Команда Toast: ошибка: "non-static method"

Tags: java, android

При добавлении метода

```
Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
```

для двух кнопок, возникает ошибка:

```
"non-static method setGravity(int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context".
```

Насколько понимаю, ошибка возникает из-за того, что класс `Toast` необходимо создать через `new` и присвоить класс `static`? Если так, то как это можно будет правильно оформить для двух кнопок?

package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    R.string.correct_toast,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    R.string.incorrect_toast,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
    MainActivity.this,
    R.string.incorrect_toast, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Метод `Toast.makeText()` является статическим и он же вам возвращает объект класса `Toast`. Методы кастомизации `Toast` вроде `setGravity()` статическими не являются и они должны вызываться только у конкретных экземпляров  класса.

Все что вам необходимо это не вызывать сразу метод `show()`, а присвоить ваш `Toast` переменной. Потом произвести с вашей переменной нужные вам настройки и вызвать уже ниже метод `show()` как в примере выше.